# Alt+drag stopped working. How can I restart a window manager?

Tags: window-manager, window-decoration

All windows are still draggable using their headers, except for Firefox. Firefox lost its window decorations and can be neither dragged nor resized.

Is it possible to restart a window manager and/or to check its logs?

Comment: What is Alt+drag supposed to do? What do you expect it to do? Did you install/remove something? Please give as much information as possible if you are having an issue.

Comment: alt-drag lets you move windows from wherever you click on them, rather than just the window headers. Very useful for applications with fixed window sizes on small screens.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Alt+Drag**

On my install (Freya) the default key for this functionality is actually <kbd>Super</kbd> (meta/windows key). You can change this in dconf-editor by navigating to `org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences` and setting `mouse-button-modifier` to `<Alt>`

**Gala (Window Manager)**

The command to respawn the window manager is `DISPLAY=:0 gala --replace &`.
Note that you should do this from a VT (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>) rather than a gui terminal so the gala process doesn't end when you close said terminal.

Comment: I know this is a little bit late but you could create a bash script file that has `DISPLAY=:0 gala --replace &` in it. Just `chmod +x` it and then run the script from the file manager. So, no more need for VT.